# Анализ куска кода на JavaScript

Tags: html, css, javascript

Добрый вечер друзья! Вопрос такой, есть кусок кода(ниже), проблема в том, что я не понимаю, что он делает(поверхностное понимание)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var step = 2;
        function expandPanel()
        {
            var panel = document.getElementById("panel")
            if (panel.clientHeight < (panel.originalHeight-step))
            {
                var h = panel.clientHeight + step;
                panel.style.height = h+"px";
                setTimeout("expandPanel()",25)
            }
            else
            {
                panel.style.height = "100px";
                var panelTitle = document.getElementById("panelTitle")
                panelTitle.firstChild.nodeValue = "Свернуть"
            }
        }
        function collapsePanel()
        {
            var panel = document.getElementById("panel")

            if (panel.clientHeight >= step)
            {
                var h = panel.clientHeight - step
                panel.style.height = h+"px";
                setTimeout("collapsePanel()",25)
            }
            else
            {
                panel.style.display = "none";
                var panelTitle = document.getElementById("panelTitle")
                panelTitle.firstChild.nodeValue = "Развернуть"
            }
        }
        function changePanel()
        {
            var panel = document.getElementById("panel")

            if (!panel.style.height || (panel.style.display == "none"))
            {
                if (panel.style.display == "none")
                {
                    panel.style.display = ""
                    expandPanel()
                }
                else
                {
                    panel.originalHeight = panel.clientHeight
                    collapsePanel();

                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: А запустить и посмотреть не пробовали?

А вообще-то там русским по английскому написано - сворачивает и разварачивает панельку с анимацией (первая часть каждого if`а).

Comment: Эту часть я понял , а вот что должно быть в HTML части не понятно , то есть что разворачивать и что сворачивать .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сворачивает и разворачивает элемент. К примеру,<div id="panel"></div>, <div id="panelTitle"></div>.

Что там - не ясно и не важно. Суть в том, что это нечто вроде tab кнопки. Которая то показала содержимое, то скрыло.